# Alternating chars and nested parenthesesin (e)grep

Tags: regex, grep

I'm looking for a regex that finds all words in a list that do not have characters next to each other that are the same. (this is an exercise)

So `abcdef` is printed, but `aabcdef` is not.

I tried both

```
egrep "^((.)[^\1])*$"
```

and
    egrep "^((.)[^\2])*$" words
but, other than being not sure which one would be right, they don't work.

I know I can go `egrep -v "(.)\1"`, but i want to use the regex in an OR structure with some other ones, so that's not possible.

For those interested, the full exercise is to find all words that have exactly two character pairs, so `aacbb` and `aabbd` are matched, but `abcd` and `aabbcc` are not.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

egrep is deprecated. use `grep -E`

eg

```
echo "aacbb" | grep -E "(\w)\1"
```

Comment: could you explain what \w does? Is it just a replacement for [A-Za-z]?

Answer (score 0):

Is egrep a requirement? Or can we switch to something more powerful like perl,python etc?

A think a negative look ahead assertion would work here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

test1 = "abcdef"
test2 = "aabcdef"
test3 = "abbcdef"

r = re.compile(r"^(?:(.)(?!\1))*$")

assert r.match(test1) is not None
assert r.match(test2) is None
assert r.match(test3) is None
```

I guess the two groups version can be made by combining three of these expressions with ones that **do** match pairs.

Comment: who says *nix tools are not powerful ? :)

Comment: this is for schoolwork, so i'm afraid only grep is allowed (how stupid that might be)